# Stop Mac OS X disk image from being mounted automatically when files on them are accessed

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, disk-image, automount, sparsebundle

I have a program that, every time it is launched, tries to read a file stored on a disk image (a sparse bundle, to be exact). If the disk image is not mounted, the program automatically attempts to mount it.

I want to change this; i.e. when the program is launched, if the disk image is not mounted, it should NOT attempt to mount it and continue as if it was on a disconnected external drive.

I'm running 10.8.

Comment: Need more info. What is the program, and why/how is it linked to the disk image?

Comment: It's Ulysses 3, a writing program that can link to external folders. It maintains a reference (not sure if it's path string, URL, symlink, etc.) to the folder which is located on the disk image. When it launches, it tries to access the folder in some way, which triggers the disk image mounting process.